# How to use utls

Tags: go, net-http

I keep getting this error:
`Get "https://www.google.com/": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x00\x00\x12\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x04\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x01\x00\x00\x1e\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01http2_handshake_failed"`

I am trying to use utls in the t1 or t2 transport and I am not sure how to do that. If anyone can help me that would be great.
I am not sure how to implement utls with my code. Do I need to put it within t1 which is a http transport or t2 which is a http2 transport? But t2 is put back into t1 and uses t1 as a transport for the client. If anyone knows how to fix it would be much appreciated.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"

    // "net/http/cookiejar"

    tls "github.com/refraction-networking/utls"
    http "github.com/useflyent/fhttp"
    "github.com/useflyent/fhttp/http2"
)

func main() {
    // Creating the transport using fhttp
    t1 := &http.Transport{
        DialTLSContext: func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            tcpConn, err := (&net.Dialer{}).DialContext(ctx, network, addr)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            config := tls.Config{ServerName: "google.com"}
            tlsConn := tls.UClient(tcpConn, &config, tls.HelloChrome_Auto)

            err = tlsConn.Handshake()
            if err != nil {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("uTlsConn.Handshake() error: %w", err)
            }

            return tlsConn, nil
        },
        ForceAttemptHTTP2: true,
    }

    // Creates http2 Transport
    t2, err := http2.ConfigureTransports(t1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }

    // Imports http2 transport into http1 transport
    t1.H2transport = t2

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: t1,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.com/", nil)
    req.Header = http.Header{
        "sec-ch-ua":                 {"\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"90\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"90\""},
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile":          {"?0"},
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": {"1"},
        "user-agent":                {"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"},
        "accept":                    {"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"},
        "sec-fetch-site":            {"none"},
        "sec-fetch-mode":            {"navigate"},
        "sec-fetch-user":            {"?1"},
        "sec-fetch-dest":            {"document"},
        "accept-encoding":           {"gzip, deflate, br"},
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(body))
    }
}
```

Comment: This issue looks relevant: https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls/issues/16

Comment: But I am using fhttp which is a fork of net/http. And I don't know how to add utls in t2 because t2 is created by the http2.ConfigureTranports function.